# Vertical Alignment issue at random places in JCST Journal

Tags: vertical-alignment, templates, parskip, journal-publishing

I am currently, writing a paper for JCST journal and facing following problem.

[image]

I have tried almost all possible solutions to fix it but all in vain. Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{JCST}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{1}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Set Page Head%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setpageinformation
%{Head of the first page} {Running head of odd pages}
{}
{ }{ }{}{Mon.}{Year}
{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%===========================================================

\begin{CJK}{GBK}{song}

\title{Long Title Long Title Long Title Long Title Long Title Long Title Long Title Long Title }

\footnotetext{footnote...}

\begin{abstract}
This paper contains a systematic literature review of studies regarding  summarizing bug reports and source codes. The rapid development of emerging technologies poses new challenges to this research field, which is still growing. And more content. This paper contains a systematic literature review of studies regarding summarizing bug reports and source codes. The rapid development of emerging technologies poses new challenges to this research field, which is still growing. And more content. This paper contains a systematic literature review of studies regarding summarizing bug reports and source codes. The rapid development of emerging technologies poses new challenges to this research field, which is still growing. And more content. This paper contains a systematic literature review of studies regarding summarizing bug reports and source codes. The rapid development of emerging technologies poses new challenges to this research field, which is still growing. And more content.
\end{abstract}

\keywords{Mining Software Repositories, Mining Software Repositories, Mining Software Repositories, Mining Software Repositories, Mining Software Repositories}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Main Text Begin %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{multicols}{2}
\normalsize
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}
Researchers employ computer programs (a software) to reduce the size of a software artifact. While doing so they aim to retain the original meanings and essential features of an artifact intact. Software artifacts are tangible byproducts that are produced and archived during software evolution. They include sources such as the information stored in source codes (e.g.,JEdit), version-control systems (e.g., the Concurrent Versions System (CVS)), bug-tracking systems (e.g., Bugzilla), and communication archives (e.g., e-mails). These artifacts carry information that helps in realizing the actual evolutionary path taken by a software system~\cite{Kagdi:2007}. For example, they include data such as the bug triage -in case of bug repository, or the comments -in case of source codes, about what the specific artifact is doing.

Researchers employ computer programs (a software) to reduce the size of a software artifact. While doing so they aim to retain the original meanings and essential features of an artifact intact. Software artifacts are tangible byproducts that are produced and archived during software evolution. They include sources such as the information stored in source codes (e.g.,JEdit), version-control systems (e.g., the Concurrent Versions System (CVS)), bug-tracking systems (e.g., Bugzilla), and communication archives (e.g., e-mails). These artifacts carry information that helps in realizing the actual evolutionary path taken by a software system~\cite{Kagdi:2007}. For example, they include data such as the bug triage -in case of bug repository, or the comments -in case of source codes, about what the specific artifact is doing.

Researchers employ computer programs (a software) to reduce the size of a software artifact. While doing so they aim to retain the original meanings and essential features of an artifact intact. Software artifacts are tangible byproducts that are produced and archived during software evolution. They include sources such as the information stored in source codes (e.g.,JEdit), version-control systems (e.g., the Concurrent Versions System (CVS)), bug-tracking systems (e.g., Bugzilla), and communication archives (e.g., e-mails). These artifacts carry information that helps in realizing the actual evolutionary path taken by a software system~\cite{Kagdi:2007}. For example, they include data such as the bug triage -in case of bug repository, or the comments -in case of source codes, about what the specific artifact is doing.

Researchers employ computer programs (a software) to reduce the size of a software artifact. While doing so they aim to retain the original meanings and essential features of an artifact intact. Software artifacts are tangible byproducts that are produced and archived during software evolution. They include sources such as the information stored in source codes (e.g.,JEdit), version-control systems (e.g., the Concurrent Versions System (CVS)), bug-tracking systems (e.g., Bugzilla), and communication archives (e.g., e-mails). These artifacts carry information that helps in realizing the actual evolutionary path taken by a software system~\cite{Kagdi:2007}. For example, they include data such as the bug triage -in case of bug repository, or the comments -in case of source codes, about what the specific artifact is doing.

This paper is organized as follows....

\end{multicols}
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

This JCST template can be downloaded from following url [JCST Submission template](http://jcst.ict.ac.cn:8080/jcst/EN/column/column63.shtml)

If document's text expands, this issue continues for example.

[image]

It appears randonmly in the document based on the text, figure and table. Any suggestion to fix this issue?

Comment: If you're publishing with a journal, you don't need to worry about the layout. In fact, it's pointless to modify their template, as they will override the changes anyway.

Comment: @engineer Wish my boss understands this. I have no choice except to fix this issue.

Comment: @David Carlisle i have posted images and MWE.

Comment: Have you tried adding the instruction `\raggedbottom` in the preamble -- *after* loading the JCST package?

Comment: @Mico yes even tried `\vspace{-2.5mm}`

Answer (score 2):

There is something wrong with the template. I haven't been able to trace exactly what, but I managed to overcome the problem using two macros in preamble

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
```

Really the style class needs to be rewritten.